# "Permission Denied" when trying to invoke yq command from within it's container

Tags: dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, yq

I have the following Dockerfile to build yq so that I can edit Yaml Files in a Jenkins pipeline.

```
FROM some_registry/some_prj/busybox:1.31.1
LABEL maintainer="this.maintainer@com"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/yq

RUN addgroup -S yq && adduser -S yq -G yq

RUN chown yq: /usr/bin/yq && chmod u+rwx /usr/bin/yq

USER yq

RUN cd /usr/bin/yq && wget "https://some_registry/nexus/repository/applications-to-deploy/yq/yq_linux_amd64"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/yq"]
```

My yq_linux_amd64 is from here - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.40.5/ and the file is yq_linux_amd64.

The image is built, but I cannot invoke the command yq from the container.
The pipeline has the following step

```
node("Build-Node"){
    
    def sourceArtefact
    stage("checkout"){
        checkout scm
    }
    stage("invoke yq"){
        docker.withRegistry("https://some_prj/harbor/", "robot_id_to_pull"){
            docker.image("some_prj/yq:v0.4").inside("--entrypoint='' -u 0:0"){
                sh "yq --version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The shell command throws an error "Permission Denied". I am confused what exactly is wrong here.

Comment: It looks to me as if your `ENTRYPOINT` is simply the directory `yq` and not an executable program. The directory cannot be executed. Are you sure you are installing `yq` in the proper way?

Comment: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/blob/master/Dockerfile
This was my inspiration for Entrypoint

Comment: "the file is yq_linux_amd64" and "I cannot invoke the command yq" are in conflict. Either rename the former to just `yq`, or create a symlink so that invoking `yq` is redirected to your `yq_linux_amd64` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `/usr/bin/jq`, then downloading the binary into it, so the binary will be `/usr/bin/jq/yq_linux_amd64`

Your entrypoint is `/usr/bin/jq` which is a folder, not the binary. (and you're overriding the entrypoint, anyway).

This works for me:

```
FROM docker.io/busybox:1.31.1
LABEL maintainer="this.maintainer@com"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/yq

RUN addgroup -S yq && adduser -S yq -G yq

RUN cd /usr/bin/yq && wget "https://some_registry/nexus/repository/applications-to-deploy/yq/yq_linux_amd64"

RUN chown yq: /usr/bin/yq && chmod u+rwx /usr/bin/yq

USER yq

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/yq/yq_linux_amd64"]
```

Note that your `sh` step would need to point to the binary, as well.

Comment: I still get permission Denied error. :-(

Comment: May it be docker itself that is lacking permissions? You haven't posted any concrete output.